# How to make equations in views.py with a model field (beginner)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model like this:

```
class Factura(models.Model):
    nombre_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
    importe_Total= models.FloatField()
    importe_sin_iva = models.FloatField()
```

And i have a view like this:

```
def ver_factura(request, id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk = id_factura)
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(factura = fact)
    template = 'verfacturas.html'

    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['fact'] = fact
    extra_context['cliente'] = cliente

    return render_to_response(template, extra_context)
```

this function shows the data of the bill (Factura in spanish) in a table. Ok. What i need is to take the value of : "importe_sin_iva = models.FloatField()" from the database and make a multiplication : (importe_sin_iva x 0.21) and show that result in the template. After that i have to take the result of this multiplication and add it (+) to the importe_sin_iva data: "result of the multiplication + importe_sin_iva "

The thing is that i want to do this in the views.py so i don´t have to make the custom template tags to handle this. With the code that i have now in the function i can access all the data from the client of this bill (Factura).

This looks like a very basic question but i would really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand if you already have the total price or the price without VAT to begin with. If I understand, you want to calculate the total cost by doing importe_sin_iva * 1.21

```
extra_context['importe_iva_incluida'] = fact.importe_sin_iva * 1.21
```

If you want to have the VAT to display in your template, just do

```
extra_context['iva'] = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I don´t have the total price. I want to calculate the total price by adding the result of this line: "extra_context['iva'] = fact.importe_sin_iva * 0.21" and fact.importe_sin_iva. How can i do that? should i save it in a variable and then do the adding?. Thank you for the help

Comment: Done. Sorry to boder you. Thanks for the help